# Keeping CSS styling when loading html page using InnerHTML

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, innerhtml

Using this code below I can load an HTML page to a div, in my site, by clicking a link in my menu.

Now, the problem is that when it loads the HTML page into the div, it loads just fine... but without its original background color that should be loaded with the other content of the HTML page as well. All the other CSS elements seem to be just fine.

Thank you in advanced.

js code:

```
function processAjax(url) 
{ 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Non-IE browsers 
        req = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        req.onreadystatechange = targetDiv; 
        try { 
            req.open("GET", url, true); 
        }
        catch (e) { 
             alert(e); 
        } 
        req.send(null); 
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE 
          req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
             if (req) { 
               req.onreadystatechange = targetDiv; 
               req.open("GET", url, true); 
               req.send(); 

    } 
} 
return false; 
} 

function targetDiv() { 
    if (req.readyState == 4) { // Complete 
          if (req.status == 200) { // OK response 
              document.getElementById("containerDiv").innerHTML = req.responseText; 
          } else { 
            alert("Problem: " + req.statusText); 
          } 
    }  
}
```

html:

```
<a onclick="return processAjax(this.href)"  href="example.html">CLICK ME</a>
<div id="containerDiv"></div>
```

Comment: It sounds like an [`iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) might be a better solution to this particular problem.

Comment: Could we see what `req.responseText` looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the style element from the page and append it to the head:

```
var styles = document.getElementsByTagName('style');
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

for(var x = 0; x < styles.length; x++){
    head.appendChild(styles[x]);
}
```

Edit:

You want to set the returned html as an element first:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = req.responseText;
var styles = div.getElementsByTagName('style');
for(var x = 0; x<styles.length;x++){
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(styles[x]);
}
```

Use the new code, not the old, and put it in the `if(reg.status == 200)` block.

Comment: PitaJ, i have problem using it, how should i merge your code with mine? do i need to put it somewhere in my js code that i published?

Answer (score 0):

Change `.innerHTML` to `.html`, or just use `.load(req.responseText)`

`.innerHTML` overwrites everything I believe. You just want to change a section.

Comment: Whoops, that's a jQuery solution, didn't read question properly. You may have to add the appropriate styles to the loaded area, instead of relying on the parent document to style an AJAX loaded item.